# SCNPhysicsShape don't allowed my car to move when apply engine force

Tags: swift, scenekit, game-engine, game-physics, scnnode

I finally manage to create a driving car in `SceneKit`, using `SCNPhysicsVehicle`.

The following code is working fine... my car is dropped in the scene, I can apply engine force and I can steer the wheels and drive the car..

but once I activate `body.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: chassie)`, the car don't move anymore.

```
   func setupVeicles(){
        let chassie = loadAssetWithName(nameFile: "rc_car", nameNode: "rccarBody", type: "scn", scale: SCNVector3(1, 1, 1))

        chassie.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)

        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
//        WHY THIS LINE OF CODE BLOCK MY CAR TO MOVE
//        body.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: chassie)
        body.categoryBitMask = BodyType.car.rawValue
        body.collisionBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue
        body.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue
        body.allowsResting = false
        body.mass = 1
        body.restitution = 0.1
        body.friction = 0.5
        body.rollingFriction = 0
        chassie.physicsBody = body
        // Load the wheel
        let wheelFL = chassie.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FL", recursively: true)!
        let wheelFR = chassie.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FR", recursively: true)!
        let wheelBL = chassie.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RL", recursively: true)!
        let wheelBR = chassie.childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RR", recursively: true)!
     
        
        let phywheelFL = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelFL, position: SCNVector3(3, 1.31, 2.753))
        let phywheelFR = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelFR, position: SCNVector3(-3, 1.271, 2.753))
        let phywheelBL = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelBL, position: SCNVector3(4, 1.31, -3.566))
        let phywheelBR = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelBR, position: SCNVector3(-4, 1.31, -3.566))
        
        physicsVehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassie.physicsBody!, wheels: [phywheelFL,phywheelFR,phywheelBL,phywheelBR])
        
        self.scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(physicsVehicle)
        self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(chassie)
  
        
    }
```

What I don't understand is why if I activate `SCNPhysicsShape` the car doesn't move anymore..
This in my mind will allow me to simulate better **Physics**.

My floor is set like this:

```
   func makeFloor()->SCNNode{
        let geo = SCNFloor()
        let matFloor = SCNMaterial()
        matFloor.blendMode = .multiply
        matFloor.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
        matFloor.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
        matFloor.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "concrete.png")
        geo.materials = [matFloor]
        
        let floor = SCNNode(geometry: geo)
        
        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.static()
        body.categoryBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue 
        body.allowsResting = false
        body.restitution = 0.1
        body.friction = 0.5
        body.rollingFriction = 0
        floor.physicsBody = body
        floor.name = "floor"
        return floor
    }
```

If I deactivate `SCNPhysicsShape` the wheel are into the ground .. looks unrealistic..

With `SCNPhysicsShape(node: chassie)` applied:

[image: imm]

without `SCNPhysicsShape(node: chassie)`:

[image: not]

Comment: Probably you can find some Information here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRZgE5sPBhPdPMEwVXQnuNhMa8ZNHvMW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hold the device in Portrait mode and then rotate it Clock-Wise to landscape. touch the screen to accelerate the car and tilt to steer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much more clear.. written with your example.. The issue was the wrong position of my wheel...Now everything work as expect.. only one doubt remain.. can't find out why I can't assign SCNPhysicsShape(node: chassisNode) to the physicsBody property of the chassisNode. If I do.. car not move anymore... I tried also in your file..

Comment: Glad I could help... the thing wiht the shape I have currently no idea why this behaves like that...